# Log4j2 Configuration for rolling file for specified format

Tags: logging, log4j2

I want to configure log4j2.xml will below configuration.If My log file size increase than 5 MB ,it should create new Files.and on next day All file will be compressed and stores into zip with date format.
    e.g
    for 01-06-2015  applog.log 2 MB,
        01-06-2015  applog.log.1  3 MB,
        01-06-2015  applog.log.2 3 MB,
        01-06-2015  applog.log.3 3 MB
    On 01-0702015 ,It all should be compressed and stored into folder applog-%d{dd-MM}-%i.zip
    My current Configuration is below:

```
<appenders>   
   <RollingFile name="applog_Appender" fileName="D:/logs/applog.log"
                 filePattern="D:/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.zip">                       
             <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="3 MB"/>
            </Policies>
       <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="15" />       
    </RollingFile>              
  </appenders>
```

With this configuration,It will create only zip with applog.log. I want applog.log ....applog.log.n of one day to be compressed and create zip

Comment: so whats the issue? Any exception/error/issues/question for us? rolling isn ot happening or compression is not happening?

Comment: With this configuration,It will create zip with only one file.

Comment: I want that for whole day's applog.log to applog.log.n  should be zipped.

Answer (score 3):

Log4j2 cannot zip multiple files on rollover. The current rollover logic simply renames the current log file and optionally zips it. That's all it does. You may need to create a custom script to combine multiple old log files into a single archive.

Update: Log4j 2.5 introduced the ability to have custom actions execute on rollover. Currently [DeleteAction](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) is the only built-in action, but you can create your own custom action to zip multiple files.

Comment: Is there any improvement as of now, or still not possible?

Comment: Added update for the custom rollover actions introduced in Log4j 2.5.